# How to let user draw on arbitrarily long canvas in Android?

Tags: android, canvas, paint, android-bitmap

I want to create an Android note-taking app where the user can scribble notes with their finger, scroll up to open up some more space when the page is full, scribble some more, and keep scrolling up, making the document longer, and scribbling as long as they like.

If I use a bitmap the (ever expanding) length of the document, the phone would run out of memory really fast.

How do I go about it? Should I be thinking of multiple bitmaps, with some sort of bitmap caching, swapping bitmaps in and out as the user scrolls up and down? Some Android feature like a Recycler view or something?

I'm afraid I can't get my head around the problem well enough to nut out a solution. I just need to be pointed in the right general direction.

thanks

John

Comment: what did you try

Comment: I tried bitmaps and quickly ran out of memory. So now I'm wondering if I try multiple bitmaps with some sort of cache management, or if I try drawing onto an uncached canvas. So I'm looking for advice before I go further.

Answer (score 0):

You should load a bitmap of specified size and load it on the canvas, then you  can draw using event listeners.

```
int width = WIDTH_IN_PIXELS, height = HEIGHT_IN_PIXELS;

Bitmap.Config config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; 
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config); 

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

An `ARGB_8888` stores 4 bytes on a single pixel. So roughly an image of 2000*2000 utilizes around

> 2000*2000 = 40,00,000 pixels

So total bytes will be 40,00,000 * 4 =

> 1,60,00,000 bytes

So in MB it will be **16MB** that won't reach a MemoryOut.

So what you can do is to load a scaled(320*320 like that requires 400KB only ) version of your larger canvas on a recyclerview, just like the feed of instagram, there by much memory won't be used, because as you scroll views will be recycled.

When the user click a particular item you can should the full bitmap on another activity so it'll be easy to handle and the user can edit the existing bitmap and save.

Comment: But how do I make it arbitrarily long? At some length it will be too large to load. What then?

Comment: The document needs to be expandable in length, as many times as the user wants to expand it. I can't create a single, really really long bitmap for the canvas to draw into, because that bitmap would quickly be too large. So I'm wondering how I can swap in new bitmaps, everytime the user expands the document length, or something .  .  .

Comment: If that's the case , using a recyclerview the image will get recycled as you scroll down.

Comment: But how do you get a canvas to draw into a recycler view of bitmaps? This is what I can't get my head around  . . . I can figure out how to display a long document. I can't figure out how to draw into a long document.

Comment: And when they make the document longer, it won't be longer by 1 screen length. They need to be able to add just 1/2 a screen length at a time, or 2/3 of a screen length, so they can still some of what they have already written.

Comment: Could you outline that solution as an answer, with a bit more detail, please? Then I can try it out and mark it as the answer.